# Rest API request not recognizing date parameter in data Python

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests

I'm trying to pull data from a rest api using python requests library.

I can connect fine with the key and can pull other locations on the API however for some reason it isn't picking up the date field

section of code:

```
    Headers = {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'cookie' : 'hazelcast.sessionId='+ token
                }

    url = 'https://uk.calabriocloud.com/api/rest/scheduling/adherence/agent/'
    Data = {
            'date':'2022-11-25'
            }


    response = session.get(url, headers=Headers, data=json.dumps(Data))
    #df = json.loads(response.text)
    print(response.text)
    print(response)
```

Response is as follows

```
    {"errorMessage":"Missing required query parameter: date"}

    <Response [400]>
```

Documentation for the API:
URI: /api/rest/scheduling/adherence/agent
Method: GET
Content Type: Multipart/form-data

Date for which you are requesting
detailed agent adherence data in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Any help appreciated

Have attempted adding the string to the url as ?date=2022-11-25 but got a server error

Answer (score 0):

Required data is "date" not "Date"

Headers = {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'cookie' : 'hazelcast.sessionId='+ token
}

```
url = 'https://uk.calabriocloud.com/api/rest/scheduling/adherence/agent/'
Data = {
        'date':'2022-11-25'
        }


response = session.get(url, headers=Headers, data=json.dumps(Data))
#df = json.loads(response.text)
print(response.text)
print(response)
```

try this code

Comment: thanks for the response, still the same error with the above

Comment: try with post method

session.post(url, headers=Headers, data=json.dumps(Data))

Comment: no luck with that, method not supported: post

Comment: my best guess is something to do with Content Type: Multipart/form-data, not something i've come accross but does this data need to be submitted a different way?